# Implementing a best match search in Java

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to get a best match string matching to work using existing Java data structures. It is quite slow though, any suggestions to improve its performance will be welcomed .

the Sample data would look like this

```
Key | V
--------------------- 
0060175559138 | VIP
--------------
006017555     | National
--------------
006017        | Local
---------------
0060          | X
--------------
```

so a best match search on the key  = 0060175552020 will return 006017555

One way I can think of is having multiple TreeMaps using hashing to divert the data into different maps hence making the search area smaller.

```
private final TreeMap<String, V> index;

public Set<V> syncBestMatch(String key) {              
    Entry<String,V> entry = index.headMap(key, true)
                .descendingMap().entrySet().stream()
                .filter(e -> isPartiallyOrFullyMatching(key, e.getKey()))
                .findFirst()
                .orElseThrow(() -> new NoMatchException("No match found"));

    Set<V> results = new HashSet<>();
    results.add(entry.getValue());
    return results;
}
```

Comment: you might consider using this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm

Comment: Someone suggested Trie too. Will take a look at them both. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `TreeMap` and the [`floorEntry(K key)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#floorEntry-K-) method:

> Returns a key-value mapping associated with the greatest key less than or equal to the given key, or `null` if there is no such key.

The following is simplified. Real code would need to search if an invalid entry is found, e.g. if the map had a key `0060175551000`, in which case you'd need to find the common prefix between the search key and the found key, then do the lookup again. Rinse and repeat.

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("0060175559138", "VIP");
map.put("006017555"    , "National");
map.put("006017"       , "Local");
map.put("0060"         , "X");

String key = "0060175552020";
Entry<String, String> entry = map.floorEntry(key);
if (entry == null)
    System.out.println("Not found: " + key);
else {
    System.out.println(key);
    System.out.println(entry);
}
```

*Output*

```
0060175552020
006017555=National
```

---

**UPDATE** There is the full code, with loop for extended search.

```
private static Entry<String, String> lookup(NavigableMap<String, String> map, String key) {
    String keyToFind = key;
    for (;;) {
        Entry<String, String> entry = map.floorEntry(keyToFind);
        if (entry == null)
            return null;
        String foundKey = entry.getKey();
        int prefixLen = 0;
        while (prefixLen < keyToFind.length() && prefixLen < foundKey.length() &&
               keyToFind.charAt(prefixLen) == foundKey.charAt(prefixLen))
            prefixLen++;
        if (prefixLen == 0)
            return null;
        if (prefixLen == foundKey.length())
            return entry;
        keyToFind = key.substring(0, prefixLen);
    }
}
```

*Test*

```
TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();
map.put("0060175559138", "VIP");
map.put("0060175551000", "Other");
map.put("006017555"    , "National");
map.put("006017"       , "Local");
map.put("0060"         , "X");

System.out.println(lookup(map, "0060175559138"));
System.out.println(lookup(map, "0060175552020"));
System.out.println(lookup(map, "0055708570068"));
System.out.println(lookup(map, "8684064893870"));
```

*Output*

```
0060175559138=VIP
006017555=National
null
null
```

Comment: `if (entry == null || !key.startsWith(entry.getKey())` but a very fine solution.

Comment: My comment is misleading, you'll need a loop with `getLowerEntry` and checks.

Comment: @JoopEggen Correct, as I stated in the answer, "[...] do the lookup again. Rinse and repeat".

Comment: My benchmark test went from 6000ms to best search 500 records to 41 ms to best search 50000 records. the exact search which basically uses a Hashmap with get() is at 19ms. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the TreeMap answer, but for completeness the same algorithm, now with binary search.

```
String[][] data = {
        { "0060175559138", "VIP" },           // <-- found insert position
        { "00601755511", "International" },   // <-- skipped
        { "00601755510", "International" },   // <-- skipped
        { "006017555", "National" },          // <-- final find
        { "006017", "Local" },
        { "0060", "X" },
};
Comparator<String[]> comparator = (lhs, rhs) -> lhs[0].compareTo(rhs[0]);
Arrays.sort(data, comparator);

String searchKey = "0060175552020";
int ix = Arrays.binarySearch(data, new String[] { searchKey }, comparator);
if (ix < 0) {
    ix = ~ix; // Not found, insert position
    --ix;
    while (ix >= 0) {
        if (searchKey.startsWith(data[ix][0])) {
            break;
        }
        if (searchKey.compareTo(data[ix][0]) < 0) {
            ix = -1; // Not found
            break;
        }
        --ix;
    }
}
if (ix == -1) {
    System.out.println("Not found");
} else {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s - %s%n", data[ix][0], data[ix][1]);
}
```

This algorithm is first logarithmic, and then does a loop.
If there are no skipped entries, logarithmic time: fine.
So the question is, how many entries need to be skipped.

**If you store at every element a reference to its prefix:** 
from `{ "00601755511", "International" },` to `{ "006017555", "National" },` then you would only need to follow the prefix back links.