# Effectivey searching a Java collection of Comparable objects

Tags: java, algorithm, search, treemap, comparable

I have a Java 8 application with an arbitrary `Map<T, String>`, where T extends `Comparable<T>`.

The easiest example uses integers:

```
Map<Integer,String> numbers = new HashMap<>(4);
numbers.put(10,"value10");
numbers.put(20,"value20");
numbers.put(30,"value30");
numbers.put(40,"value40");
```

I want to search this Map for the key that is close to an arbitrary input value, rounding up, unless no key exists that is greater, then round down. For instance:

- input -5 returns key 10 (round up to the smallest key that is larger then input)
- input 8 returns key 10 (round up to the smallest key that is larger then input)
- input 10 return key 10 (exact match)
- input 11 returns key 20 (round up to the smallest key that is larger then input)
- input 40 return key 40 (exact match)
- input 100 returns key 40 (round down, no key exists that is greater than 10)

I have a working implementation that naively loops over all keys, does all necessary comparisons and returns the best matching key based on these criteria. My application needs to check the same Map for different values often so this naive lookup can become a bottleneck. As demonstrated in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39503919/implementing-a-best-match-search-in-java), I believe a sorted TreeMap might significantly increase the lookup time, but this class is a bit too complex for me to understand without some guidance .

- Which methods of TreeMap can I use to implement this lookup?
- How would the algorhitm below be simplified by using advantage of the fact that a TreeMap is sorted?
- If not TreeMap, is another data structure more suited for this?

Here is the naive (but working) implementation. The Collection is actually the Map's Keyset:

```
private T getBestMatchingKeyForValue(Collection<T> keys, T value)
{
    T bestMatchingKeySoFar = null;

    for (T keyToCheck : keys)
    {
        if (bestMatchingKeySoFar == null)
        {
            bestMatchingKeySoFar = keyToCheck;
        }
        else
        {
            int valueComparedToBestMatching = value.compareTo(bestMatchingKeySoFar);
            int valueComparedToKeyToCheck = value.compareTo(keyToCheck);
            int partitionTocheckComparedToBestMatching = keyToCheck.compareTo(bestMatchingKeySoFar);

            int signValueComparedToBestMatching = Integer.signum(valueComparedToBestMatching);
            int signValueComparedToKeyToCheck = Integer.signum(valueComparedToKeyToCheck);
            int signKeyToCheckComparedToBestMatching = Integer.signum(partitionTocheckComparedToBestMatching);

            if (signValueComparedToBestMatching == signValueComparedToKeyToCheck)
            {
                if (signValueComparedToBestMatching == signKeyToCheckComparedToBestMatching)
                {
                    bestMatchingKeySoFar = keyToCheck;
                }
            }
            else if (valueComparedToKeyToCheck == 0)
            {
                bestMatchingKeySoFar = keyToCheck;
            }
            else if (valueComparedToBestMatching != 0)
            {
                if ((this.preferUpperBound && partitionTocheckComparedToBestMatching > 0)
                        || (!this.preferUpperBound && partitionTocheckComparedToBestMatching < 0))
                {
                    bestMatchingKeySoFar = keyToCheck;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bestMatchingKeySoFar;
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)?

Comment: @DavidConrad actually the relevant parts for me where in the documentation of NavigableMap (see the methods ued by accepted answer) and SortedMap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TreeMap`'s floor and ceiling methods do exactly what you're looking for:

```
TreeMap<K, V> map = ...
K search = ...
K closest = map.ceilingKey(search);
if (closest == null) {
    closest = map.floorKey(search);
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that classes that already implement Comparable (such as enums, integers and strings) use that ordering when being inserted & sorted in a treemap? How can I deviate from that logic (eg, let an enum be sorted alphabetically by name rather than by ordinal?)

Comment: @user1884155 Look at tree map documentation. It tells you